# Cake PHP - Form Validiation doesn't work

Tags: php, cakephp-1.2, validation

my CakePHP (1.2.5.) doesn't validate my form correct.

```
 $this->UserData->save($this->data);
```

gives me always a true value back. I can't find the problem. The label for UserData.nichname works.

That's the View:

```
<?php
echo $form->create('UserData');
echo $form->error('UserData.nick_name');
echo $form->input('UserData.nick_name', array('id' => 'UserDatanick_name', 'rule' => 'alphaNumeric', 'label' =>'Nickname:', 'error' =>'false'));
echo $form->end( array( 'label' => ' Save ') );
?>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
class UserDatasController extends AppController {
  var $name = 'UserDatas';
  function add(){
     if (!empty ($this->data)){
         $this->UserData->create();
         if ($this->UserData->save($this->data)){
             $this->Session->setFlash('input is valid');
         } else {
             $this->Session->setFlash('input is not valid');
         }
     }
  }
}
```

The rules for are not in the model, that's the reaseon i don't post it.

What else is necessary for a validation?

Thanks in advance
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^^ also check what your files are called.
you have named your model file user_data.php right? and your controller user_data_controller.php?

Note the underscores because of your CamelCasing. If you get the model file name wrong, it wont complain but will instead use a default magic model - which could be why your validation rules within the model didnt get picked up.

Answer (score 1):

The validation rules have to be defined in the model, not in the view, see also the [chapter about data validation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/125/Data-Validation) in the cakebook.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only specify the rules in the model, but the label would be kept in the $form->input() function